# Some strings from a .mo file do not load

Tags: plugin-development, localization

In a plugin I'm developing, most translations do work, but some strings refuse to work without an apparent reason.

For a settings page, I'm using this pattern:

```
$clgs_settings_descriptions = array(
    'notification_severity_filter' => __( 'Minimum severity for notification in adminstration menu', 'custom-logging-service' ),
    'def_severity_filter' => __( 'Default minimum severity filter on log page', 'custom-logging-service' ),
    'manager_role' => __( 'Roles that can manage Custom Logs', 'custom-logging-service' ),
    'log_entries_per_page' => __( 'Log entries per page', 'custom-logging-service' )
);

function clgs_settings_init() { 
    global $clgs_settings_descriptions;

    //..

    foreach ( $clgs_settings_descriptions as $key => $desc ) {
        add_settings_field( 
            $key, 
            $desc, 
            'clgs_field_render', 
            CLGS_OPTION_PAGE,
            CLGS_GROUP,
            [ $key ]
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'clgs_settings_init' );
```

These four strings are present in the custom-logging-service-de_DE.po file:

```
#: includes/settings.php:3
msgid "Minimum severity for notification in adminstration menu"
msgstr "Mindestschweregrad für Benachrichtigungen im Administrationsmenü"

#: includes/settings.php:4
msgid "Default minimum severity filter on log page"
msgstr "Standard-Mindestschweregrad auf Log-Seite"

#: includes/settings.php:5
msgid "Roles that can manage Custom Logs"
msgstr "Rollen mit der Fähigkeit, Freie Logs zu verwalten"

#: includes/settings.php:6
msgid "Log entries per page"
msgstr "Log-Einträge pro Seite"
```

The .mo file is current. There are other translatable strings in the same file, if I change them and run the gettext stack, I can see those translations appearing in the rendered page.

It's only these four strings that remain untranslated.

Can anyone spot why they are not working?

**Update 2016-2-3**: As a patch, I am now calling `add_settings_field` like this:

```
    add_settings_field( 
        $key, 
        __( $desc, 'custom-logging-service' ), 
        'clgs_field_render', 
        CLGS_OPTION_PAGE,
        CLGS_GROUP,
        [ $key ]
    );
```

It works, but I wouldn't say it is the intended pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this again, I finally saw it: `$clgs_settings_descriptions` is defined globally, during plugin load. The textdomain is loaded at action hook `plugins_loaded`, which is obviously later...